# Lavu POS API - Send order to KDS

Tags: php

I am facing problem in integrating the Lavu POS API. I hope to get some answer from peers that integrate Lavu POS API before. The documentation for Lavu POS API is very difficult to read and understand. Columns are not well explained.

I tried their send order API PHP codes. The codes that is provided in their basic API document.

So basically, I've created a order and order content successfully. The orders are seen on runner iPad. But when I click "send", it says that my order are already send to the kitchen. However, the KDS does not receive any order.

I notice that the order ID created from Lavu POS API codes is different from the order that are created from the app.

In the API order example created orders with ID that start from 7. In my app order created orders with ID that start from 1.

Both are order content are the same.

so my question is:

1. why KDS doesn't get my order?
2. What is the parameter I am missing?
   3/ what is the parameter I had send wrongly?

Below is the content the I send to Lavu POS API for order:

Note: server and server id is changed in my real code

```
$set_contents = "
<row>
    <opened>".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."</opened>
    <closed>0000-00-00 00:00:00</closed>
    <subtotal>8.30</subtotal>
    <taxrate>0.000</taxrate>
    <tax>0.98</tax>
    <total>8.30</total>
    <server>Ancori</server>
    <server_id>15</server_id>
    <tablename>Table 5</tablename>
    <cash_paid>8.30</cash_paid>
    <change_amount>0</change_amount>
    <cash_applied>8.30</cash_applied>
    <card_paid></card_paid>
    <gift_certificate></gift_certificate>
    <guests>2</guests>
</row>
";
```

Below is the content i send to pos lavu for order content:

```
$set_contents = "
    <row>
        <sent>0</sent>
        <order_id>" . $order_id . "</order_id>
        <item>testing item</item>
        <price>8.30</price>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <options></options>
        <special></special>
        <modify_price></modify_price>
        <check>1</check>
        <seat>1</seat>
        <item_id>666</item_id>
        <printer>1</printer>
        <apply_taxrate>0</apply_taxrate>
        <custom_taxrate>0</custom_taxrate>
        <course>1</course>
        <subtotal>8.30</subtotal>
        <discount_amount></discount_amount>
        <discount_value></discount_value>
        <discount_type></discount_type>
        <after_discount></after_discount>
        <subtotal_with_mods>8.30</subtotal_with_mods>
        <tax_amount></tax_amount>
        <notes></notes>
        <total_with_tax></total_with_tax>
        <after_gratuity></after_gratuity>
        <void>0</void>
        <discount_id></discount_id>
        <server_time>".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."</server_time>
        <device_time>".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."</device_time>
    </row>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `<send_status>1</send_status>` in your order

if you didn't set this value, by default it will be 0, '0' means order has been sent to printer, so you need to set to 1 while you sending order to indicate that the order hasn't be printed.